Unstable Kafka node after restart
Dears,
Today morning I changed the log level from DEBUG to INFO in log4j.properties file and did restart nodes one by one.
Now I have problems with my kafka cluster. One node is unstable, Kafka service restarts every few minutes.
I log file there is many lines like this one:
[2024-04-04 08:24:16,019] WARN [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-26, dir=/kafka_data] Non-monotonic update of high watermark from (offset=986277 segment=[986274:554]) to (offset=986274 segment=[986274:0]) (kafka.log.Log)

and:
[2024-04-04 06:47:57,451] ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/2, node already exists and owner '216214412779454482' does not match current session '72057609474473995' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)
[2024-04-04 06:47:57,451] ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/2, node already exists and owner '216214412779454482' does not match current session '72057609474473995' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)
[2024-04-04 06:47:57,457] ERROR [KafkaServer id=2] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:126)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.getAfterNodeExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1904)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1842)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1809)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:96)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:308)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2024-04-04 06:47:57,457] ERROR [KafkaServer id=2] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:126)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.getAfterNodeExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1904)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1842)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1809)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:96)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:308)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

How to solve this problem?
Best regards,
Dan
